# Android studio hypervisor driver is not installed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

when starting a virtual machine, the Android SDK is up to date gives the following error.

```
Running Android Emulator hypervisor driver installer
Requesting administrative privileges...
‘Ґўаа бЕЕўўў Windows Windows (Microsoft R) ўабабаб 5 5.812
Copyright (C) Љ аЇ а 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 1996-2006, ў Ї Ї ў § § § §....

Done
```

[image]

It gives this error when installing hypervisor
Also, a cmd with the inscription Requesting administrative privileges appears constantly in cycles
AMD's percentage Turned on SVM in the bios, also turned on hyper v in the control panel and all the ticks in it did not help, running the program on behalf of the administrator did not help

AMD's percentage Turned on SVM in the bios, also turned on hyper v in the control panel and all the ticks in it did not help, running the program on behalf of the administrator did not help

Comment: That looks like a defect binary. I would uninstall and reinstall android-emulator in SDK manager.